# Tag merge request: [file] and [file-management]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I don't see difference between [file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) and [file-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) looking either at names and already tagged questions.